# Limit app switcher to active display

Tags: spaces, window-manager, switching, application-switcher, dual-screen

When pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>  , I want to cycle through **only** the apps on the display that contains the app which currently has focus or contains the cursor. Likewise, when pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+ <kbd>`</kbd> , I want to limit the windows to the current display.

In my MS Windows environment, I've accomplished this with [VistaSwitcher](http://www.ntwind.com/software/vistaswitcher.html). Is there a similar product or native feature in OS X that makes this possible?